# Magnific-Popup: Multiple Instances of an Inline object on a gallery page?

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I have a gallery that uses magnific-popup on inline 'more info' links. What I want is to get the popup content for each link that is clicked (since they're different), but I only get the result for the first link no matter what link I click.

I've already tried using `each()` and gallery. I don't want a gallery and `each()` did nothing. I'm still learning javascript, so I'm sorry for any mistakes.

Thank you for the help.

**The solution**: Since I'm working in Flask, I used loop.index to iterate the results. Then I got id_1, id_2, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both popups link to `#small-dialog` element. Besides that there can be only one element with the same ID on page.

Comment: I figured that was the problem. I couldn't figure out how to make everything work without removing the ids. I figured out how after sleeping on it. Thanks for the great plugin!